# C# Orientation in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm amateur in Windows Phone,
how can i auto change size for orientation in Landscape mode and Portrait mode?

in C# WinForms i can use Dock or Anchor and it totally works fine but in windows phone i can't.

here is my XAML code, is that possible help me?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testApp"
    x:Class="testApp.DLPage"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="#FF262626"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" >
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn" />
            </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardOut" />
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
                <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardOut" />
            </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
    </toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

        <Grid x:Name="gridOrg" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" Height="800" >
            <Grid x:Name="gridPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="780" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" Background="#FF3E3E3E">
                <Ellipse x:Name="elp" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="455" Margin="4,4,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="453" Tap="elp_Tap"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,478,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="162" Width="447"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="cntDL" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,662,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="52" Width="447"/>
            </Grid>


            <local:LoadingControl x:Name="pb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,377,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460"/>


        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

i try to set Width in auto for all controls but didn't work.

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to resize the controls when changing the orientation state?

Comment: not just for orientation, for all resolutions! because i can set app for nokia lumia 520, but i can't fix this app to 720p or 1080p resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your UI to look the same no matter what screen size or ratio it's launched on. You could use [canvas controll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx) and place the elements of your interface inside it, but the only answer you should go with is: don't use hard-coded values, use **stars** and **Auto** instead. Your UI is going to look great on every screen. *Your columns/rows are going to stretch/shrink to fit the height and width of the user’s phone.*

More info and examples:
[Multi-resolution apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206974(v=vs.105).aspx)